# change weekly calendar to month wise calender

Tags: wordpress, plugins, calendar

i am using the following code for weekly calendar it shows like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMfy9.png)
     function tribe_events_get_days_of_week( $format = null ) {

```
        switch ( $format ) {
            case 'min' :
                $days_of_week = Tribe__Events__Main::instance()->daysOfWeekMin;
                break;

            case 'short' :
                $days_of_week = Tribe__Events__Main::instance()->daysOfWeekShort;
                break;

            default:
                $days_of_week = Tribe__Events__Main::instance()->daysOfWeek;
                break;
        }

        $start_of_week = get_option( 'start_of_week', 0 );
        for ( $i = 0; $i < $start_of_week; $i ++ ) {
            $day = $days_of_week[ $i ];
            unset( $days_of_week[ $i ] );
            $days_of_week[ $i ] = $day;
        }

        return apply_filters( 'tribe_events_get_days_of_week', $days_of_week );
    }
```

but, i want to display in month wise. how can i change my existing code.